# How to use the index values returned by nlargest() in Pandas in a second data frame?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'd like to find the n largest numbers in one data frame and take the corresponding values in a second data frame.

The code below shows what I am trying. Is it possible to do this?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 10, 8, 20, -1]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [3, 20, 4, 11, 14]})

df.nlargest(2, 'a')
df2[df2 == df.nlargest(2, 'a')]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
df2.loc[df.nlargest(2, 'a').index]
```

This will work if your dataframes are indexed the same.

Output:

```
    a
3  11
1  20
```